# Smart Phone flash tool - Readback - EMMC_USER backup

Tags: backup

I trying to take backup of my phone. and i use **Smart Phone Flash Tool**

> How can i take (**EMMC_USER**)(64GB Rom) in **HEX** ?

Can someone tell me what HEX i need in length in **Smart Phone Flash Tool**, in tab (Readback, **EMMC_USER**)

Or are there a better way to take backup of the phone without root access.

Comment: you need to perform ram test to get the size for EMMC_PART_USER https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-21972.html

Comment: But i got MT6765 but the SP Flash Tool does not support it, it says only (DRAM flip test)

Answer (score 2):

I have answered this very question probably a hundred times in 4 Years.

So instead of wasting time rewriting it all, i made video on how to do it on YouTube.

Instead of just Self Promoting that video as some would see it, Here goes 101.

1. Remove Battery or Turn Off the Device
2. Go into Memory Test Tab - SPFT
3. Tick Whatever Options are Available - Just make sure something is ticked.
4. Start the Test and Place your Battery back IN
5. Plug your Phone In
6. Once the Test Starts, Immediately Stop the Test
7. Now Focus on a small Panel in the Bottom Left,
   ( This info is read from the device when connecting )
8. OK, Now sellect EMMC section in the Panel
9. Look at EMMC_USER Size in the info

With this info, you can DUMP the Entire device - Or, Split the Dump into Partitions.

DUMPING IS USELESS ON ANDROID 9.0+

ANDROID 9.0+ MANDATES FACTORY SIGNED FIRMWARE ... BACKUPS WONT RESTORE 100%

I CAN RESTORE ONLY - PROJECT TREBLE RELATED PARTITIONS.

OLDER THAN ANDROID 9.0+ DUMPING AND RESTORING IS STILL OK.

DUMPING PRE 9.0+ ( AVB 2.0 )

10. Open Read Back Tab
11. Creat a new ReadBack file called EMMC_USER
12. Set the REGION to EMMC_USER
13. Set The Start to 0x0
14. Set the Length to the Size of EMMC_USER in the small panel ( bottom left )
15. Make Sure Device is Unplugged Prior to Doing any New Action - This is because a Handshake is made on each connection to the preloader, the preloader handshake is only good for One action each connection ( read, write , etc )
16. Press Start ReadBack
17. Plug - In device
18. Wait for 16 GB to download at around 21 MB per second.
19. Now Dump Preloader
20. Go ReadBack and Make a new ReadBack of Both EMMC_BOOT0 and EMMC_BOOT1

Sometimes both Partitions are required.

The usual dump length for both is  0x40000

and start is always 0x0 because your dumping the whole thing from 0

Comment: i wouldn't say backup is useless because once bootloader is unlocked you can restore from custom recovery (adb push)

Comment: https://youtu.be/pJHGAql2xAc here's a new video that cuts the long stuff out ogmf my old one.

Comment: pls where is the video?