# SU binary exists, but not executeable (no error while executing from terminal, just empty)

Tags: rooting, root-access, unrooting

My friend is having a little problem with his phone where he can't update or use banking software on it because of root even though he has never rooted it and root checkers gave me mixed results, some says its rooted and some says its not rooted. So after looking around i downloaded a terminal and ran "su", it ran without errors, but it didn't do anything and didn't output anything.

Now, im not fully sure if this is what is causing his phone to not be able to update, but it does seem odd to have the su file on the phone without it actually being rooted, my guess is that the phone was bought used and the previous owner was attempting to root the phone but failed and just gave up. So, now me and my friend are trying to find a way to get his phone "unrooted" even though its technically not rooted. What should we do?

Comment: I just asked him and apparently he bought it new, so either he got scammed or its normal to have the su binary already on the phone...

 Also the phone is a Redmi Note 4 Mediatek

Comment: best is flash stock ROM, also you can check if bootloader is unlocked already, this would allow you to boot custom recovery from fastboot

Comment: how do i check the bootloader?

Comment: also, how do i flash the stock ROM? can i do it from the original recovery?

Comment: in settings - developer options - oem unlocking must enabled also there must be mi account registered. check `fastboot oem device-info` https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads you can flash with XiaoMiFlash (if locked) or unlock with Mi Unlock Tool and flash from fastboot or twrp

Comment: my friend just checked and it is still locked...

Comment: But why would applications like the google play store detect root if the phone is not even unlocked?

Comment: xiaomi shipped with su or leftover of rooting apps. you can delete it from mtk-su shell

Comment: i was unable to delete it from mtk-su, read-only filesystem. do i have to remount it as r/w?

Comment: yes you must remount /system or /

Comment: but will modifying files in /system cause problems? like i heard people having bootloops after mounting partitions as rw  and doing modifications

Comment: also, its not my phone so i don't want to cause a bootloop/brick the phone

Comment: yes that is called dm-verity, be prepared for unbricking

Comment: there is a video for backup in the comments https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220584