# How can I enable USB debugging using ADB? My phone is recognized only in sideload mode

Tags: usb-debugging

I am trying to unlock a USB debugging disabled device from ADB.

The device is recognized by ADB only when it is connected through USB in recovery mode (when the device is turned on, it is not recognized as USB debugging is off). .`/adb devices` is returning the device serial and identifying that it is in sideload mode.

Any further command like .`/adb shell` is returning "error:closed".

What can I do in this sideload mode? Any way to enable USB debugging while the device is recognized to be in sideload status?

I have tried some commands to unlock a different USB debugging enabled device I have at home and the commands work on that device.

So for now my first roadblock is enabling USB debugging in this locked device or something to that effect. Please give me some advice in this regard.

Any other advice on unlocking the device without losing data would be very helpful too.

Thank you.

More details: I am trying to unlock an Android phone that has stopped taking the correct password after a auto-restart. I know the PIN, I have not changed it in a long while. The phone stopped accepting the PIN after the sudden auto-restart so I am just clueless what may work. Hard reset is not an option for this device without backing up the data so willing to try anything that may help.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to unlock. Are you talking about bootloader unlocking? If so, that has nothing to do with `adb`. Sideload mode is used in recovery to flash ROM zips. If you want to use `adb` commands you need a custom recovery like TWRP (which requires an unlocked bootloader). Both (unlocked bootloader and `adb` sideload mode in recovery) has nothing to do with ADB in ROM (enabled through Developer Options). So please clarify what you exactly want to achieve (the actual problem other than enabling ADB).

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I am trying to unlock an Android phone that has stopped taking the correct password after a auto-restart.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you please clarify what you mean by "usb-otg adapter and teensy". Willing to try anything that would save the data.

Comment: I know the PIN, I have not changed it in a long while. The phone stopped accepting the PIN after the sudden auto-restart so I am just clueless what may work. Hard reset is not an option for this device without backing up the data so willing to try anything that may help.

Comment: @BushraFerdousKhan please [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/221762/edit) your question to include the details.

Comment: Done, added more details in the question.

Comment: I did try google device manager. I am able to set up a new password but then it says, "since I have a lock screen password set the new password (set through device manager) won't be used." I am using a Xiaomi Redmi Note 4. Thanks for trying to help. Every bit of suggestion helps

Comment: Can I flash in a custom recovery using adb in the sideload mode? I need to get out of this sideload mode first to try anything further

Comment: for qualcomm you can flash twrp with locked bootloader in EDL mode, there is exploit for splash.img for this. for mediatek use sp flash tool

Comment: Great! Will do. Can you please guide me through the process? Sorry if that would be asking too much. I am really not a tech person so can't proceed without precise guidance.

Comment: Mine is qualcomm btw. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, I will search based on the keywords you suggested for now. Will give you a link after opening a thread on xda tomorrow as well. Thanks a lot for your help. Hope you have good day!

Comment: Here is the new thread I created on xda: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/help-unlock-xiaomi-redmi-note-4-wiping-t4061651

Comment: consider full ROM dump. maybe you can unlock bootloader the official way, and restore (encrypted) userdata + metadata partitions from TWRP afterwards https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220584