# Formatted whole Flash

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, stock-rom, formatting, flashtool

i perfomed a format whole flash on my leagoo kiicaa android device using SP flashtool, after that i flashed the firmware file on it and it was successful. but the phone would not power on or show any sign of life even after flashing again. please what can i do community?
the phone was getting stuck on the logo screen each time i powerit on so i decided to flash it, after the flashing process the problem still persisted so i did a format whole flash and then flashed the stock rom on it again hoping it would solve the problem but unfortunately the phone did not power on or charge after that although the system still detects it whenever i connect it.i used the download only option to format it, and i used MT6580.txt as the scatter file. my phone's model is LEAGOO KIICAA POWER....here is the link for the firmware i used http://www.mediafire.com/file/a3z3m9uh7djgdbs/Leagoo_Kiicaa_Power_MT6580_20170915_7.0.zip/file

Comment: good news: "Download Only" option does not format whole flash. preloader seems still working. important partitions for IMEI and calibration data are still valid. bad news: flashing ROM does not fix previous problem (must have other cause, maybe hardware related). it seems there are different models T591/T592 (not sure if ROM is different). i recommend to make full ROM dump and split into partitions with Wwr MTK for further examining. If scatter file looks good it should be possible to flash lk and boot to make fastboot working. in fastboot check bootloader unlock status and flash from fastboot

Comment: please how do i perform a ROM dump and the other things you recommended, i dont av a clue

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220584

Comment: when i'm trying to do a readback of the emmc and i click on add, it adds a file and names it ROM 0 and i couldn't edit anything there, i was unable to set the region, length and start address as u explained in the above link. what could be wrong?

Comment: i av done that not working

Comment: thanks i got now

Comment: i am afraid your phone can not be fixed with a single Q&A. post link to your xda thread for further support

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/223638/formatted-whole-flash

Comment: check out this [xda thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3783271) there is ROM for different hardware (revision R2)