# MediaTek K80 is stuck , computer store tells me the firmware chip is corrupted

Tags: factory-reset, boot-loop, factory-image

To start with I did a factory reset to wipe out my files and apps before giving my tablet to my niece.
After the reset the tablet is stuck at the screen with the android guy in the corner and MEDIATEK across the screen. it will not boot any further. I took the tablet to a repair store and 3 days later he tells me the chip is corrupted and he cant(be bothered?) do anything because its a Chinese clone?

I have researched many sites but cannot find a scatter file or rom image etc.. the following is  what I have found inside my tablet:
On a stickered chip:

```
E960 V1.2 YK18091021
6580A/WA/1+16/3G/B15
GXQ 2018/09/26
DL_BT_MM_QC_
```

ALSO, TAKEN FROM "ABOUT TABLET" :

```
Android Version:7.0
Android Security Patch level: 1Feb.2016
Baseband version:  MOLY.WR8.W1449.MD.WG.MP.V23, 2017/05/16  17:00
Kernel version: 
3.18.19
c@c-S2600JF #2
ThuOct11 17:29:47 cst 2018
Build Number:
MRA58K test-keys
Custom Build version:
E960v1.1_HJC_03_3G_HBOE_FL_WXGA_bigbattery_4_64
```

I am completely lost and would really appreciate any help possible.
Thank you in advance,
John Sweeney

Comment: No offense, but these are disposable devices... Unless you can find the original firmware image, which is literally impossible on most of these devices, and you have a JTAG programming tool ($100-$350) it's probably a lost cause, I would go into recover and attempt a factory reset again, twice to make sure. But the tech is probably right, its not worth attempting to repair. The other kicker here is in the info, notice "test-keys" in the build number? That means it likely wan't an authorized use of Android either, common among these generic tablets.

Comment: Because the device is may be considered disposable (which is probley 80% of all electronics today) but that doesn't mean one can't try to fix it or at least learn something new.   Test-Keys  appeared after the factory reset because I think I hit the wrong command key the 1st time ... they were all in chinese....

Comment: "Test-keys" is based on how the software is built or compiled, not anything you did... You don't have what most legitimate Android devices would have production keys, in other words they never went so far as to sign (digitally) their own build. Again, you need the full ROM image to repair this, or in your case the scatter file (essentially the full rom image) used by MediaTek devices. You can try the stuff listed below, but it is unlikely this device will every be recoverable.

Comment: create your own scatter file with WwR MTK. preloader works 100% even on dead device without battery https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2XWTAYmNUo

Comment: hold power button ~ 10-30 sec to power down. when powered off, hold Vol up + Power to enter recovery menu, select *"reboot to bootloader"* to enter fastboot mode

Comment: this firmware might work on your device also. but do not flash preloader. make sure you have backup. do a readback (full ROM dump) first https://tunisia-firmwares.com/duoduogo-tablet

Answer (score 0):

The kernel version 3.18.19 is correlative with Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow, which also correlates with Security Patch level. The ROM is built userdebug test-keys so this is most likely (ported) custom ROM.

Looking for baseband version there are lot of different 'brands' for several phones or tablets, which is unusual.

What they have in common these are low-budget devices running entry-level MT6580 processor with serial number 0123456789ABCDEF in fastboot mode.

Indeed this looks like a typical chinese clone device often with fake android version and/or fake hardware specs (see [#40386](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&hl=en&u=https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=331715%26st%3D40384)).

Nevertheless factory reset will not have such negative impact, only cache + userdata partition is formatted which does not harm the firmware/ROM.

The best source for 'stock' ROM is your device itself. Do a read back with [SP Flash Tool](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220584) and create your own scatter file with [WwR MTK](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203283)

---

check that device has unlocked bootloader and/or adb root access in recovery mode. download [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) and enter recovery/bootloader mode with volume keys

in bootloader mode factory reset by formatting `cache` + `userdata` from `fastboot`

```
fastboot devices
fastboot oem unlock
fastboot format cache
fastboot format userdata
```

---

in recovery mode formatting `cache` + `userdata` from `adb shell` with `mke2fs` (where `mmcblkp1p99` is placeholder for partition number of the block device)

```
adb devices
adb shell ls -l /dev/block/*/*/*/by-name
adb shell mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblkp1p99
```

---

Reboot your device and wait a long time. device is encrypted on first boot, that might take up to 15 minutes

Comment: Thank you .... Looks like I have a lot more learning to do but when I do I will try the above  directions.  I have all ready tried using the sp flash tool but it tells me to load a scatter file. which I dont have, and the tablet is frozen on android screen.. anyways will keep trying to figure it out...